# Javascript and DOM - Date and Time

Tags: javascript, datetime, if-statement

I am creating a resume site and I'm trying to create a function that will load when the page loads that displays a greeting (as a heading) depending on the time of day. Here is what I have so far (you can ignore the salary calculator part):

```
    <body onload = "onLoad()">
        <div id="fulldiv">
    <p> Enter the following information to find out if the potential salary is too little, almost enough, or a good salary.</p>

    <p>Hourly Wage:
    <input type="text" name="wage" id="txt_wage" value ="0.00"/></p>

    <p>Hours Per Week:
    <input type="text" name="hours" id="txt_hours" value= "0.0"/> <br/><br/>

    <button value="calculate" onclick="calcSalary(); validateForm(); validateFormH()">Calculate</button></p>

    <p id="results"></p>
    <p id="resultstext"></p>

    <script src="salaryExternal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function onLoad() {
        var d = new Date();
        var z = d.getHours();
        var greeting;
        if (z < 12) {
            greeting = "Enjoy the rest of your morning!"
        } else if (z < 17) {
            greeting = "Enjoy the afternoon!"
        } else {
            greeting = "Have a good evening!"
        }
        }
        var firstVariable = document.createElement("h1");
        var secondVariable = document.createTextNode(d);
        firstVariable.appendChild(secondVariable);
        document.getElementById("fulldiv").appendChild(firstVariable);
    </script>


            </div>
```

Nothing is showing up when I load the page. I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't do anything with the greeting. You need to put it into some visual element, right now its just a JavaScript variable.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying. Can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: Something like `document.getElementById('results').textContent = greeting;`. Also note the point made by @zepplin in that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `greeting` variable as text node value and move HTML element creation code inside `onLoad` funtion as follows -

```
<body onload="onLoad()">
<div id="fulldiv">
    <p> Enter the following information to find out if the potential salary is too little, almost enough, or a good salary.</p>
    <p>Hourly Wage:
        <input type="text" name="wage" id="txt_wage" value="0.00" />
    </p>
    <p>Hours Per Week:
        <input type="text" name="hours" id="txt_hours" value="0.0" />
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <button value="calculate" onclick="calcSalary(); validateForm(); validateFormH()">Calculate</button>
    </p>
    <p id="results"></p>
    <p id="resultstext"></p>
</div>

<script src="salaryExternal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function onLoad() {
    var d = new Date();
    var z = d.getHours();
    var greeting;
    if (z < 12) {
        greeting = "Enjoy the rest of your morning!"
    } else if (z < 17) {
        greeting = "Enjoy the afternoon!"
    } else {
        greeting = "Have a good evening!"
    }
    var firstVariable = document.createElement("h1");
    var secondVariable = document.createTextNode(greeting);
    firstVariable.appendChild(secondVariable);
    document.getElementById("fulldiv").appendChild(firstVariable);
}
</script>
```

Comment: your welcome! please upvote and accept answer if it solved you question.

Answer (score 0):

The last few lines of your code are defined outside the `onLoad` function:

```
function onLoad() {
...
}
var firstVariable = document.createElement("h1");
var secondVariable = document.createTextNode(d);
firstVariable.appendChild(secondVariable);
document.getElementById("fulldiv").appendChild(firstVariable);
```

which is why it does not work as expected.